# VS Code Javascript Intellisense in svelte never has worked

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, svelte

I would love to have standard Javascript intellisense in .svelte files  section just like I have in standard .js files. It would also be nice to have jsdoc support.

I'm not sure this is possible, but if so **I would really appreciate some help getting it working.**

I have the following extensions enabled
Svelte for VS Code
svelte-intellisense

I also have "Document This" installed but it doesn't like .svelete files. Any way to enable in Svelte?

Comment: Hope it's not because you misspelled `.svelte` (you wrote `.svelete` which is wrong)

Comment: Make sure to follow the setup instruction of the Svelte for VSCode extension. Maybe you have `"files.associations": {"*.svelte": "html" }` in your settings, which should be removed.